# "Command errored out with exit status 1" error while installing pytorch

Tags: python, pip, pytorch, package

While installing any package using pip the same error occurs again and again. Earlier the error was Environment error so I used the command :`pip install --user pytorch` but again an error started occurring as :

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\rachi\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, 
os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\Wondershare\\CreatorTemp\\pip-install-sl2341tq\\pytorch_e91f041838de48259fd31f183263d4ca\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\Wondershare\\CreatorTemp\\pip-install-sl2341tq\\pytorch_e91f041838de48259fd31f183263d4ca\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\pip-record-o8hob45r\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\rachi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\Include\pytorch'
```

I don't know what to do. I am new in python. Also attaching the image of log(terminal) while installing.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is explicit. The package is not `pytorch` but `torch`

```
> pip install torch
```

```
    Exception: You tried to install "pytorch". The package named for PyTorch is "torch"
    ----------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

> pip install pytorch

After this if you're facing with .whl file installing.. Then I'd suggest try installing this.

> pip install <path to .whl file>

Answer (score 1):

According to the [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/pytorch/):

> You tried to install “pytorch”. The package named for PyTorch is ["torch"](https://pypi.org/project/torch/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to disbale your firewall or antivirus. I encountered an error while installing a package, however the error was not this, but after disabling the protection it installed smoothly.